# Problem following worm gear tutorial with loop cut

Tags: modeling, scripting

I'm following the YouTube Tutorial: [How to Instantly Model a Throated Worm and Matching Wheel in Blender 2.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVtr80IF-yI) and modeling on Blender 2.92. My problem starts at [time @9:47](https://youtu.be/jVtr80IF-yI?t=587).

When I try to loop cut, I don't get what is shown on the tutorial.
Mine spirals down into the gear not around to the blank area.
Also, I can't move the end only the start.

Can someone please look at what I've done so far and offer a few suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Interestingly similar to this. Do you know this person who posted this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272988/blender-python-script-issues-can-someone-explain-the-script

Comment: No, not me and not the same tutorial.

Comment: ah ok just a coincidence then you're both on Otvinta. btw, fwiw, you can update to any version of blender on Windows 7. I have all versions from 2.93 to 3.3beta on Windows 7 so it's possible :) and you can use https://blend-exchange.com to attach blend file. In the tutorial you just have to hover your mouse over that area and press `Ctrl`+`R` then scroll your mouse to add loopcuts and click to confirm.

Comment: Otvinta has multiple calculators for gears in Blender.

Comment: Otvinta has multiple calculators for gears in Blender. IT tried multiple versions from 2.93 and up all errored out stating you need Windows 8.1 of higher. They wont do hacks to get it running.    I followed the tutorial and got a different result. The loop cut followed the existing vortices instead of creating new ones.  Watch the video to see it.

Comment: I have windows 7 and blender 3.3 works perfectly :) here's the tutorial i made: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3RGmnRTig8

Comment: yeah i already saw it, it's very simple. can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Thank you for making and sharing the tutorial. The blender file is attached.  Thank You.

Comment: you're welcome :) i have posted the answer with explanations with what went wrong in the modeling process. you can download the fixed file https://blend-exchange.com/b/1lQGE7Zy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your model which I have fixed. Notice that you have triangulation taking place and this does not work with the [`Loop Cut`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html). You need quad topology for it to work. So I deleted the edges with <kbd>X</kbd> *> Delete Edges*.

[image]

The other problem is you have duplicate overlapping vertices. How did I know? I selected all vertices with <kbd>A</kbd> and then did <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance* which removed several thousands (~15k) of duplicate vertices.

[image]

After the clean up, I noticed that there is a problem that caused [`Bridge Edge Loops`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bridge_edge_loops.html) to triangulate your faces which will not work with *Loop Cuts*. It turns out you have too many vertices, $322$ to be exact, at the top most loop instead of $255$ vertices like in the tutorial. The bottom vertices were correct at $255$ vertices.

Another issue is that your top circle is not the proper size, notice that I positioned the 3D cursor at the center of this loop and it should have been aligned with the *World Origin*. So I deleted the top and bottom loops and [repeated the steps starting at @8:20](https://youtu.be/jVtr80IF-yI?t=500).

[image]

Now [redoing the steps at @9:47](https://youtu.be/jVtr80IF-yI?t=587) will work properly without triangulation and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for *Loop Cut* will now work. Use the scroll forward mouse wheel to add 3 cuts.

[image]

I have uploaded the fixed file here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!

This is exactly what I was looking for.
What was wrong with the drawing and how to correct it.
This is being done as a learning project.
I want to go thru the process of correcting it myself.

A couple of questions:
 
1) "With "X > Delete Edges".
     How did you select just the edges to delete or did you just select all?

2) "With  "M > Merge By Distance".
     How did you show the number of vertices in selection?
     How could you tell which were duplicates?

Ran out of space. Second part of the questions follows.

Comment: Second part to questions.

3) " top circle is not the proper size"
       Was this due to the duplicate vertices?

      "I positioned the 3D cursor at the center of the top loop"
       I positioned the 3D cursor at the center of the gear.
       Was that wrong?
       How did you center on the top loop?
       
4) "aligned with the World Origin"
      Were to find "world orgin" and how did compare the two?

5) "Use the scroll forward mouse wheel to add 3 cuts"
     "how to do this with keyboard only?

Comment: How do I rate/score the Answer?

Comment: somewhat there 2 circles overlapping with different vertex count, so i deleted 1 circle and then i discovered that 

the other circle also needed to be redone because it had more than 256 vertices. so i ended up deleting it as well. 

then there were some rogue vertices that needed to be dissolved (`x` > dissolve vertices). you can't see them if you 

are in face or edge mode. press `1` to switch to vertex mode to see all the vertices. for Q1: press `2` to switch to 

edge select mode then press `c` to circle select and swipe through all the vertical edges to select them.

Comment: Q2: when you press `1` you can switch to vertex select mode, but you can be in any mode when doing `m` *> Merge by Distance*. you won't know which vertices were overlapping, if they have faces, then you can sometimes see that the faces overlap each other. for vertices, sometimes when you select a vertex and it doesn't have that orange highlight falloff to all branching edges then you can know it's overlapping. but mostly it is irrelevant to know which were overlapping because you just select everything w/ `a` and `m` *> merge by distance* to make sure no duplicate vertices exist.

Comment: you can right click the bottom status bar and select *Scene Statistics* to see how many vertices, faces, edges, etc are in the object and how many you have highlighted, that's how i knew how many vertices i highlighted in the circle. It says Verts: X/X | Edges: X/X | Faces X/X etc. Q3: no. `Ctrl`+`C` is enough to set 3D cursor to the center (World Origin). i'm not sure how it happened, but your procedure is correct, nothing special to do there. Q4: with center i referrred to world origin where the red/green/blue axes intersect.

Comment: Q5: when you press `Ctrl`+`R` you can just type `3` to add 3 cuts, you can see what you are typing in the lower left corner when in loop cut mode. then press `enter` then press `esc`. hope this has clarified it :)