# How to delete the angle line between vertices (red arrow) and also add vertices at (yellow arrows)

Tags: vertices

How to delete the angle line between vertices (red arrow). What are they called?
How to add vertices at (yellow arrows).
How to add faces after to close the gap off?
[image: Snap_of_gear_gap]

Thank You

[image: Image for 4th comment]

Comment: duplicate to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273096/problem-following-worm-gear-tutorial-with-loop-cut which explains the reason for your triangulation, you have too many vertices at the top compared to the bottom loop with which you want to bridge edge loops with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem following worm gear tutorial with loop cut](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273096/problem-following-worm-gear-tutorial-with-loop-cut)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options come to mind.

- In this particular case, you can discriminate the diagonals by their length, so (with one edge selected,) <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *Select Similar > By Length*, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> *Dissolve*, should do it.
- More generally, with all the relevant faces selected, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> *Tris to Quads* should do it, too.

Comment: Thank You, first part worked. The second part "More generally, with all the relevant faces selected, AltJ Tris to Quads should do it, too." did nothing.  Do I need to add vertices to the edge first to "bridge edge loops"?

Comment: Hi @B.Teddy ! Ahh. That's because, on closer inspection, those are not tris. There are extra vertices in the perimeter. You could lose those verts  from the selected perimeter, if you wanted to, with a Shift-G > No. of connected edges + Ctrl-X Dissolve, or an X > Limited Dissolve.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. The extra vertices were created when the spin tool was used. 256 steps per rotation and 360 degrees were the values used. When the selected rings are "Bridge edge looped" An unwanted lid and extra walls connected from the top ring to points down inside the gear are created along with the wanted walls. How are the unwanted verts are deleted leaving the wanted side walls?

Comment: Answered here and on https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273096/problem-following-worm-gear-tutorial-with-loop-cut. Thank You